# How await works without async function in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I failed to understand how the below code successfully executes in node(version 14) without any compilation error. As far as i know await keyword has to be inside async function.

```
import axios from "axios";

for (let i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
   console.log(`executing iteration ${i}`);
   let val = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i}`);
   console.log(val.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using a new feature "top level await" which allows you to use `await` at the top level of a module without being in an `async` function.  Recently added to node.js.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await